# Ideas on optimization of DRA and energy consumption of a pipeline

Tags: pipelines, energy

I have a 200 mile pipeline with a few pump stations in between.  I am trying to find ways to optimize the electricity and DRA consumption, and was wondering if anyone has ever done something similar before?

Currently, I am building models of the outlet flow rate as a function of energy and DRA. I am also building models of the flow *normalized by energy* as a function of DRA usage, vice versa.  Is there any other more proper ways to do this optimization?

The formal problem would be: How to achieve optimal flow rate with least DRA / electricity usage.

**Data**

Flow rate at the beginning and end of the pipeline 
Current of the pumps at the intermediate pump housing 
DRA ppm  at several pump stations

Comment: viscosity of fluid pumped? cost of changing viscosity cf change in pumping costs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike!  I think all DRAs in the world are supplied by Conoco, so I'll check in the documents to see if we can do something like that.